# Mostar ventana nueva a través de una etiqueta <a> o <button> con electron js

Tags: javascript, html, electron

me gustaría poder hacer que al momento de dar click en home, me pueda abrir una pequeña ventana con electron js,  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const { title } = require('process')


const createWindows = () => {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1320,
        height: 885,
        resizable: false,
        transparent: true
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
    
    
    const child = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    })

    child.loadFile('FacturaCarga.html')

}




app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindows()
    app.on('activate', () =>{
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindows()
    })
})



app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

Ya pobré varias formas, desde crear un boton en javascript y traerlo a html con text/javascript, tambien crear usar la función "onclick" en html y traer la función de js, busqué ejemplos y los usé tal cual y no me funcioná, no se si haya alguna otra forma, alguien podría darme alguna sugerencia? :c

Comment: +1 por el título de la ventana. Sin embargo, es necesario que nos muestres _cómo_ intentaste usar el onclick en el html, por ejemplo.